# Using _set.filter(id = 4) Django field fetch

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, django-queryset

Here is my problem

[image: Trying to fetch the title field inside the _set all queryset in Django as you can see on the terminal window below]

I'm trying to fetch the data from from page model which is connected to Subject model with a foreignkey. Is there any way on how to fetch the data quickly?

Here is my views.py
[image: Views.py]

urls.py

[image]

I'm trying to fetch the field title form page_set.filter object.

here is my models.py

```
from django.db import models
from ckeditor.fields import RichTextField
# Create your models here.


class Subject(models.Model):
 title = models.CharField(max_length = 200)
 slug = models.SlugField(blank = False)
 visible = models.BooleanField(default = True)
 position = models.IntegerField()
 date_published = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add = True)
 date_updated = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=False)

 def __str__(self):
    return self.title


class Page(models.Model):
 subject = models.ForeignKey(Subject, on_delete= models.CASCADE)
 title = models.CharField(max_length = 200)
 slug = models.SlugField(blank = False)
 description = models.TextField()
 thumbs = models.ImageField(blank = True)
 visible = models.BooleanField(default = True)
 position = models.IntegerField()
 date_published = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add = True,auto_now=False)
 date_updated = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=False, auto_now=True)


 def __str__(self):
    return self.title
```

class NewsFeed(models.Model):

```
 title = models.CharField(max_length = 200)
 slug = models.SlugField(blank = False)
 description = models.TextField()
 thumbs = models.ImageField(blank = True)
 visible = models.BooleanField(default = True)
 position = models.IntegerField()
 date_published = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add = True)
 date_updated = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=False)


 def __str__(self):
    return self.title
```

Comment: Please don't paste code as picture.

Comment: you need to call `.get()` instead of `.filter()` on Queryset on `a.page_set`

Comment: show your models, and no pictures please

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `Page.objects.filter(id=4)` results in a **`QuerySet`** of `Page`s, not a *single* `Page`. Even if the `QuerySet` contains one element, it is not a `Page` (like a list with one number, is not a number). Or as specified in the [**`filter(..)`** documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/models/querysets/#django.db.models.query.QuerySet.filter):

> Returns a new **`QuerySet`** containing objects **that match the given lookup parameters**.

You can use `Page.objects.get(id=4)` to obtain a `Page` object (given it exists, and only one such object exists, otherwise it will raise an error). Or as specified in the [**`get(..)`** documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/models/querysets/#django.db.models.query.QuerySet.get):

> Returns the **object matching the given lookup parameters**, which should
>   be in the format described in Field lookups.
>
> `get()` raises `MultipleObjectsReturned` if more than one object was
>   found. The `MultipleObjectsReturned` exception is an attribute of the
>   model class.
>
> `get()` raises a `DoesNotExist` exception if an object wasn’t found for
>   the given parameters. This exception is an attribute of the model
>   class.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback I was looking for a fast answer, I disregarded the .get method instead I used the filter from the tutorials. I've used the .get method now and it works perfectly. Regards